# Linking Code::Blocks custom libraries error (cannot find)

Tags: c, compilation, linker, codeblocks, linker-errors

I'm struggling with the Code::Blocks IDE when programming in C.

I use one custom library, named "main.h".

Yesterday, when I begun working on the library, the program compiled without errors. I even put some functions written on the library on my source file and it built and ran fine.

Today, when trying to recompile the whole project after some modifications, appeared the "undefined reference" error.

I searched it over on this site, I tried to follow the steps another user proposed but now, instead of the "undefined reference" error, appears the "cannot find -l[filename]".

I tried to collect information about this error on this site as well but, I understand, it's a OS problem and, apparently, never happened to other Code::Blocks users.

I use Windows 7 64 bit, in case this is the problem.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put fullpath to library in build options of your project and be sure to put it in the right build scheme(Debug/Release) or both to be sure.

However it is quite strange name for library - "main.h". Is it "main.h.dll" or what? Maybe it is header file? If it is so and you put implementation of you functions in .h file and not in .c, some errors could occur.